# Set bare compile mode for CoffeeScript Play 2 framework

Tags: coffeescript, playframework-2.0

in the documentation of Play 2 framework says that for a `bare` compilation of CoffeeScript files one should use:

`coffeeScriptOptions := Seq("bare")`

My `Build.scala` looks like this and I don't know how to add that option.

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(

    // Add your own project settings here      
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/RyJhslhuMRM/zw8dXqmh0cEJ

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    coffeescriptOptions := Seq("bare")
)
```